# What price side am I paying when shorting stock / future

Tags: stocks, shorting-securities, futures

I know that question was asked here numerous times but I don't think it was ever answered clearly.

**When I'm short selling a security** (stock/future...) I pay a **bid price** (with a MKT order - when I want to have my order filled immediately) and **when closing this** position I am paying **ask price** (I'm actually purchasing to return the security I've borrowed and sold).

**When I'm buying a security** I pay **ask price**, **when closing** I pay **bid price** (I accept a highest bid on security I currently own).

Am I right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct.

Think about is this way:

If someone makes a **bid** - they are placing a bid to buy something. So if you want to sell something, you need to find a buyer, and would be getting the *bid* price.

Similarly, if someone is selling something, they are **ask**ing for money in return, so when you buy a security you pay the *ask* price.

Another way to think of it is the bid is always lower than the ask (hence the bid-ask spread.  Since you can't sell something immediately for a higher price than you pay for it, you always get the lower price (bid) when you sell and pay the higher price (ask) when you buy.

Comment: Thanks!  With short selling am I also correct? Thats what I'm quite uncertain.

Comment: Yes. Whether you're opening a short position or closing a long position, selling is selling.